# Creating Average based on Subtracted Data in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I want to count the number of books delivered per country, per month and also generate the average time it took to deliver the book.

I have the following columns *book_title*, *Country_Delivered*, *OrderDate*, *DeliveryDate*

The results should look like this;

|Country|Month|Number_Books|Average_Delivery|

I am using Postgres

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(OrderDate, 'YYYY-MM') year_month
      , Country 
      , count(*) Number_Books
      , avg(DeliveryDate - OrderDate) Average_Delivery_days 
from tablename
group by to_char(OrderDate, 'YYYY-MM') ,Country
```